# Enable access to Authenticated users only for 'layouts/user.aspx' page

Tags: user, access

I want to enable access to all Authenticated users only for page `layouts/user.aspx`.

They should be able to read the contents in this page.

It has to be done across thousands of sites. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to

1. Inherit your page from `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase`
2. Override the `AllowAnonymousAccess` property and return `true`

   ```
   protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess 
   {    
     get{    
            return true;    
        }    
   }
   ```